# Why does Spring Boot discover but not instantiate a @Component?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with the following structure

```
com.package
   Application - annotated with @SpringBootApplication
   Configuration - annotated with @Configuration
   Component1 - annotated with @Component, constructor annotated with @Autowired
com.package.subpackage
   Component2 - annotated with @Component, constructor annotated with @Autowired
```

My application class is

```
package com.package;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

When I start the application both `Component1` and `Component2` are identified as candidate components. However, only `Component1` is instantiated.

`Component2` will only instantiate when I make either of the following changes

1. I move it to `com.package` i.e. the same as `Component1`
2. I declare it as a `@Autowired` field in `com.package.Configuration`

Why does Spring Boot discover the component but not instantiate it in this case? Are there differences in how `@ComponentScan` works with regards to discovering vs instantiating `@Component`?

Comment: I removed my answer because I did not get the package structure. Can your bean be lazily instantiated @Lazy or lazy-init=true? That would match the described behaviour

Comment: How are you testing that it isn't instantiated? Each component should be created regardless if it is used or not. Please add your `Application` class.

Comment: I'm testing by logging in the constructor and @PostConstruct method. @Lazy(value = false) does not make a difference.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted components and configuration class file too.

Comment: I seriously didn't find anything wrong in this code, 'coz it looks fine to me by project structure as well as annotation **@Component**.

Comment: @xenteros why is PostConstruct risky for components?

Comment: @Mark because you don't have any guarantee that anything would be injected so far

Comment: @xenteros even when everything is autowired via constructor?

Comment: @Mark I believe so, but I base on personal experience with a problem I once solved by removing post construct. Maybe you should ask Baeldung?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. Turns out Component1 was blocking the main thread stopping Component2 from being initialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was not an issue with Spring Boot itself.

The `@PostConstruct` method for `Component1` was blocking the main thread hence `Component2` was not initialised.

Using `@Autowired` or moving to the same package obviously triggered the `@PostConstruct` method of `Component2` before `Component1`.