# Compatibility of SBDG with VMWare Tanzu Gemfire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

The latest version of VMWare Tanzu Gemfire is currently 9.10.12, which is based on Apache Geode 1.12. However, from the [compatibility matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Boot-for-Apache-Geode-and-VMware-Tanzu-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix), it seems like the compatible SBDG version 1.3.x has already reached EOL.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016442/spring-boot-geode-unsatisfied-dependency-expressed-through-method-sessionregion/66020141#66020141) that later versions of Geode clients are not compatible with older versions of Geode servers. Does it mean that if we are using VMWare Tanzu Gemfire, we would be restricted to SBDG 1.3.x and Spring Boot 2.3.x, which are no longer under OSS Support? Is there any way of using  Spring Boot versions (2.5.x and 2.6.x) that is still under OSS support with Gemfire, or is migrating to Apache Geode the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at and read ***Spring Boot for Apache Geode*** [Issue #78](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/issues/110).  This question has been answered there.

Also, specifically look at/read my last [comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/issues/110#issuecomment-992923201).